# BigQuery - Split by Delimiter Only Once

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to split by a delimiter only once?  My data may have the delimiter at more than one index.  I'd like to be able to cleave a field into two separate fields.

E.g. I'd like the string **how.now.brown.cow** to split into two fields when using a period as the delimiter: [how, now.brown.cow].

SPLIT({field}, 'delimiter')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] works fine to get the first part, but I may have unequal array lengths in my data, so I'm having trouble concatenating the other indices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'how.now.brown.cow' col UNION ALL
  SELECT 'how'
)
SELECT col, 
  SPLIT(col, '.')[OFFSET(0)] AS first_item,
  ( SELECT STRING_AGG(item, '.' ORDER BY OFFSET)
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(col, '.')) item WITH OFFSET 
    WHERE OFFSET > 0
  ) AS rest_of_items
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row col                 first_item  rest_of_items    
1   how.now.brown.cow   how         now.brown.cow    
2   how                 how         null
```

Note: above is just one of the way of doing this. Looks like there are many ways of doing same result - for example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'how.now.brown.cow' col UNION ALL
  SELECT 'how'
)
SELECT col, 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, r'^([^.]*)\.?') AS first_item,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, r'^[^.]*\.?(.*)$') AS rest_of_items
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row col                 first_item  rest_of_items    
1   how.now.brown.cow   how         now.brown.cow    
2   how                 how
```